# How to loop a big dataframe and count the frequency?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(Q1 = sample(c("y", NA), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/2, 1/2)), 
           Q2 = sample(c("y", NA), 20, replace = T, prob = c(2/3, 1/3)), 
           Q3 = sample(c("y", NA), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/3, 2/3)))
```

Above data `df` is example, has only 3 columns `Q1`,`Q2`,`Q3`.

I want to know how many rows when `Q1=='y'`and `Q2!='y'` and `Q3!='y'`,I run `count(subset(a,Q1=='y' & is.na(Q2) & is.na(Q3)))`
I want to know how many rows when `Q1=='y'`and `Q2=='y'` and `Q3!='y'`,I run `count(subset(a,Q1=='y' & Q2=='y' & is.na(Q3)))`
Then I can put the result into a table as:

```
    only select this column | select this column with next column 
Q1        2                     6
```

Finally,the expect result as below:

```
   only select this col | select this col with next col | select this col with 2 next cols | total
Q1        2                     6                                2                        10
Q2        4                     2                                2                        8
Q3        1                     1                                2                        4
```

How to do it when `df` has many columns?

Plus:
In my R 3.3,`df` is:

```
     Q1   Q2   Q3
1  <NA> <NA>    y
2  <NA>    y <NA>
3     y    y    y
4     y    y <NA>
5  <NA>    y <NA>
6     y    y    y
7     y    y <NA>
8     y    y <NA>
9     y <NA>    y
10 <NA>    y    y
11 <NA>    y <NA>
12 <NA>    y    y
13    y    y <NA>
14 <NA>    y <NA>
15    y <NA> <NA>
16 <NA> <NA> <NA>
17    y <NA> <NA>
18    y    y <NA>
19 <NA> <NA> <NA>
20    y    y <NA>
```

There'are 20 answers of 3 questions.How many people only answer the first quesiotn `Q1`?How many people answer the first question `Q1` and the second question `Q2`?How many people answer all questions `Q1` and `Q2` and`Q3`?

Comment: `table(rowSums(!is.na(df)))` would give how many people answered `0, 1, 2, 3` questions individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have `n` questions i.e. `ncol` and want to find the number of people who answered first, first and second, first, second, and third, and so on, we can use a loop

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
            sapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) sum((rowSums(dat[seq(i)] == 'y',
        na.rm = TRUE) == i) & (!rowSums(!is.na(dat[-seq(i)])))))


}


n <- ncol(df)
t(apply(matrix(seq_len(n), ncol = n, nrow = n + 1)[-(n + 1), ], 1, 
           function(i) f1(df[i])))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    6    2
#[2,]    4    2    2
#[3,]    1    1    2
```

#### Update

If the elements are not `NA`, and is 'x' then  change the function slightly

```
set.seed(1)
df2<-data.frame(Q1 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/2, 1/2)),
Q2 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(2/3, 1/3)),
Q3 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/3, 2/3)))



f2 <- function(dat) {
            sapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) sum((rowSums(dat[seq(i)] == 'y',
        na.rm = TRUE) == i) & (!rowSums(dat[-seq(i)] != 'x'))))


}

n <- ncol(df2)
t(apply(matrix(seq_len(n), ncol = n, nrow = n + 1)[-(n + 1), ], 1, 
        function(i) f2(df2[i])))
#.    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    6    2
#[2,]    4    2    2
#[3,]    1    1    2
```

Comment: This is ok, but when you have 20 columns,that's not a smart way.

Comment: There'are 20 answers of 3 questions.How many people only answer the first quesiotn Q1?How many people answer the first question Q1 and the second question Q2?How many people answer all questions Q1 and Q2 andQ3?

Comment: very close to the answer.just clarify the logic,not `find the number of people who answered first`,but `find the number of people who only answered first`.`the number of people who only answered first`=`the number of people who answered first`-`the number of people who answered first and others`

Comment: yes,this is the answer.but that answer is only for the `first question`.how to loop your answer to each question?

Comment: `[1] 2 6 2` is correct.that's the answer for `Q1`.for `Q3`,the logic is:`only Q3`,`Q3 & Q1`,then `Q3 & Q1 & Q2`

Comment: for `Q2`, all columns are `Q2 & Q3 & Q1`

Comment: If changed `NA` to `x` in a new `df`,`df<-data.frame(Q1 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/2, 1/2)), Q2 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(2/3, 1/3)),          Q3 = sample(c("y", "x"), 20, replace = T, prob = c(1/3, 2/3)))`,how to change function `f1`?